# How to split one column into two in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

So, I am new to SQL. I want to split a column into two. The values are separated by colon (:). I used,

```
Select Left([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])-1) as [Cost Center]
       ,Substring([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])+1,
                  len([Cost Center1])-Len(Charindex(':', [Cost Center1]))
                  ) as [Project]
from Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table];
```

But the problem with the above is that it only provides the view. I want to update my table. How to do that? TIA.

Comment: When you say you want to update your table, can you give a bit more detail? Can you give some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Say, I have a column named Cost Center. It's values are as follows,

5000:CORP
3001:Blah
6000:hfsdh

and so on. 

I want that the numerical values stay in Cost Center, while the character values are separated into another column called Random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add 2 more columns

```
ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD NewColumn1 varchar(100)

ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD NewColumn2 varchar(100)
```

and update their value

```
Update  Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
SET NewColumn1 = Left([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])-1),
    NewColumn2 = Substring([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])+1,
                  len([Cost Center1])-Len(Charindex(':', [Cost Center1]))
```

or you could add 2 [coumputed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)

```
ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD NewColumn1 AS Left([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])-1)

ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD NewColumn2 as Substring([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])+1,
                  len([Cost Center1])-Len(Charindex(':', [Cost Center1]))
```